# how to insert property in all objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to add properties in all object which is present in array.I will explain more in other words I have array of objects .I need to add “selected” property in all object .The value of “selected” property is true for first two object and for rest element it is false .I need to add “selected” :true for first two element and  for rest it is “selected” :false

Secondly can we remove those object from array which have property "hidden" : true , ?

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic']).controller('firstCntrl',function($scope){


    $scope.copyArrary =[];
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function(value,key) {
      console.log(value + key)
    }); 
})
```

js fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/93afL7kq/1/

Comment: What have you tried ? Do you know native Array#map() ? underscore _.filter() ?

Comment: could you please use codepen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove I would filter first:

```
$scope.data = $scope.data.filter(function (element) {
   return !element.hidden;
}
```

after that set the properties:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; ++i) {
   $scope.data[i]['selected'] = i <= 1;
}
```